# Android: android:minSdkVersion=8 causing problem to my button views

Tags: android, android-layout, android-2.2-froyo

I'm using `StateListDrawable` and `LayerDrawable` for displaying buttons programatically. 
It is working fine,  but after adding `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />` to my manifest file, the buttons are stretched and looking ugly.

Here is my sample code...

```
Drawable btnNormal = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button1);
Drawable btnPrssed = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button2); 

Drawable cnLogo = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.logo);
Drawable rightArrow = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow);

Drawable[] cnDrawablesNormal = new Drawable[]{btnNormal, cnLogo, rightArrow};
LayerDrawable cnLayersNormal = new LayerDrawable(cnDrawablesNormal);
cnLayersNormal.setLayerInset(1, 10, 1, 250, 1);
cnLayersNormal.setLayerInset(2, 280, 17, 20, 17);  

Drawable[] cnDrawablesPressed = new Drawable[]{btnPrssed, cnLogo, rightArrow};
LayerDrawable cnLayersPressed = new LayerDrawable(cnDrawablesPressed);          
cnLayersPressed.setLayerInset(1, 10, 1, 250, 1);
cnLayersPressed.setLayerInset(2, 280, 17, 20, 17);  

states.addState(new int[] {android.R.attr.state_pressed},cnLayersPressed);
states.addState(new int[] { }, cnLayersNormal);
```

I didnt change anything, can anybody explain why it is causing prob, and fix for it.

Thanks in advance.

-venkat papana

Comment: What did you change from? Have you checked patch notes on the methods you use, to see if they have beeen changed.

Comment: What is the target Android SDK of your project? What build target have you used for development?

Comment: It is `target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:8` in my default.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar problem, I solved it by adding the `android:targetSdkVersion` value in the AndroidManifest so it will look something like this

`<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="8" />`

Comment: thanks for your answer; but it is not working for me :( any guesses?

Comment: aahh to bad, but I think the solution is gonna be such a "weird" thing. I would suggest you try to use a different `minSdkVersion`.